# Efficient Root Finding Algorithm for a Transcendental Equation

Tags: roots, approximation

I hope the image below captures the details of the problem in which I'm trying to find the multiple roots of $f(s)$ for $s<w$ given $w>0$. The constants $a,b,c,d$, and $w$ are all real-valued and positive with in addition $d>1$, and the plots of $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are for the specific values indicated.

[image]

The function $g(s)$ is related to $f(s)$ according to

$$g(s)=\frac{f(s)}{\cos[P(s)]\cos[aQ(s)]}$$

so that they share the same zeroes. However, the asymptotes to $\pm \infty$ of $g(s)$ do not line up with the extrema of $f(s)$. The zeroes however, are bracketed by the asymptotes which contrary to what I had at first suspected do not correspond to either

$$P(s)=\pm (2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$

or

$$aQ(s)=\pm (2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I need suggestions for an algorithm more efficient than a linear search and bisection, that I can encode in a VBA module of an Excel spreadsheet. I need these zeroes to be able to apply the Cauchy Residue Theorem to the inversion of a Laplace transform that arises out of the solution to a transient diffusion equation.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Newton's method (on the original function $f$)?

Comment: It's on my agenda, but the problems that I see with a Newton Raphson iteration are
1) The zero slope at the extrema of $f(s)$ which will cause the algorithm to break down
and
2) Once a root is found, how to make a good guess for the next root.

Comment: I was hoping that the asymptotes of $g(s)$ would line up with the extrema of $f(s)$, but (a) they don't, and (b) are not easily evaluated.

Comment: The brackets in the denominator are not balanced.

Comment: My apologies. Now balanced. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Your comment confuses me: Are you trying to find the roots of $f$ or the extrema of $f$?

Comment: The roots of $f(s)$. I mention the extrema because they are likely to be problematic in applying a Newton-Raphson type of iterative method.

Comment: I've attempted an answer below and welcome comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since the roots are bracketed, I suggest  that you use a method which combines Newton and bisection steps (bisection being used when Newton tends to take you out of the range). This is extremely efficient.

If you go [here](http://astronu.jinr.ru/wiki/images/8/8c/NumericalRecipesinF77.pdf), on page $359$, you will find subroutine $\text{RTSAFE}$ ([here](http://iop.vast.ac.vn/%7Envthanh/cours/numerical_methods/code/CH2_newton_BS.f) and [here](http://adh.usace.army.mil/svn/adh/PT123/trunk/src/util/rtsafe.f)) which does exactly what you want. It is very robust.

I apologize for giving you a reference to Fortran coding. If you can access the books of Numerical Recipes, you will find the equivalent in $C$ and $C$++.

Answer (score 0):

If I create a function $h(s)$ by dividing $g(s)$ by $P(s)\tan[P(s)]$, then the asymptotes are at

$$
\bar s_k=\Biggl[\Bigl(\frac{k\pi}{b}\Bigr)^2+w\Biggr], k=1,2,\cdots
$$

so that the zeroes are now bracketed. I now work only with $f(s)$. I start with the right (higher) end of the interval and sample $f(s)$ in equal increments towards the left (lower) end until a sign change is detected. I then use the mid point between the last two sample points as an initial guess and use a Newton-Raphson procedure which should converge in a handful  of iterations to the root.